# United States Map

Tags: word, geography, jigsaw-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

*The answer is a timely word*
*No rotations; all pieces are oriented correctly*
*The colors are not important or necessary to distinguish*

[image: U.S. Map]

[image: Puzzle Pieces]

Comment: rot13(Ner nyy gur chmmyr cvrprf fhccbfrq gb svg ba gur znc? V'z pbhagvat sbhe uhaqerq rvtugrra pryyf va gur cvrprf naq sbhe uhaqerq gjryir pryyf va gur znc vapyhqvat gur erq barf.)

Comment: @cap oops ignore the duplicate sized reddish rectangles. Can't fix until tonight, or someone can.

Comment: Omit one of the two 3x2 rectangles?

Comment: @robpratt Yep, I thought there was one too many and then I recounted and couldn't find it.

Comment: @Amoz I've submitted an edit. Hopefully this is what you want? If not, feel free to reject it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whew!

The puzzle fills in like this:

> [image]

Each puzzle piece is

> a US state. The number of cells in each piece is the number of letters in the state's name.

The marked cells

> [image]
>  from west to east spell INDEPENDENCE, which the USA will be celebrating on the 4th of this month. Happy Birthday, USA!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the tiling is not unique.  Here's another one:

> [image]

Comment: You are right, the tiling is not intended to be unique as this is also about geography to a reasonable degree. You must have been inspired by the xkcd comic! : )

Comment: What does this one spell?

Comment: @DertereuuiFloireiurtrthr The corresponding letters would be A A C E E H H H I K N W, which don't seem to form an English word.